# How to read the font of the title in UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uifont

How do I get the `UIFont` of the title in `UINavigationController`? I attempted to read it like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Some text here";
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"navigation bar title attributes = %@", self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes);
    NSLog(@"title font = %@", [self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes objectForKey:UITextAttributeFont]);
}
```

The output was disappointing. The `titleTextAttributes` dictionary only contained one key/value, which was not the font.

```
navigation bar title attributes = {
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1";
}
title font = (null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the subviews of navigation bar to get the titlelable and get font

```
for (UIView *sv in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews)
{
    if (sv.subviews.count > 0 && [sv.subviews[0] isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)sv.subviews[0];
        NSLog(@"%@",lbl.font);
        break;
    }
}
```

Console output

```
<UICTFont: 0xd8a3e50> font-family: "Helvetica-Light"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 16.00pt
```

Comment: Keep in mind that code like this is fragile and could break after an iOS update.

Comment: yaa @rmaddy i know its too bad to go for view in subviews.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. But keep in mind that there is a default font used if no font has been set for the specific `UINavigationBar` or through the `UIAppearance` proxy.

To determine the default font if you don't find a specific one, use the `UIFont` class methods `systemFontOfSize:` and `systemFontSize`.

Comment: The documentation for `systemFontSize` says *Returns the size of the standard system font.* How can there be a standard size when the sizes of text varies in different views?

Comment: That's a good question. See if it gives you the right result or not.